# Is it a problem of al titosh Torah imecha if you use a different nusach hagadah than your family's minhag?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, nuschaot, mesorah-tradition

Is it a problem of "al titosh Torah imecha" if you use a different nusach hagadah than your family's minhag?

Comment: Does it tell the same story?

Comment: What explicitly dou you mean by a "different nusach"? Please add more detail and explain where your difference arises and why. I know of one person who found that his family was originally sfardi but had lost that a generation or two back. Others might learn differently in Yeshivah and should stay with the family minhag. You need to give more details.